# Проблема с transform

Tags: jquery, css

Здравствуйте. Возникла одна проблема.
Имеем сайт с блоком-рулеткой. По таймеру рулетка запускается и крутится с помощью

js:

```
$('.all-players').css({
 transform: 'translate3d(-7800px, 0px, 0px)',
 transition: '16000ms cubic-bezier(0.32, 0.64, 0.45, 1)'
});
```

css:

```
.all-players {
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: none;
    list-style: none;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

html:

```
<ul id="usersCarousel" class="all-players">
<li>123</li><li>123</li>
</ul>
```

После определенной паузы рулетка должна крутится опять, но этого не происходит и она стоит на месте.

Пробовал удалять блок .all-players после прокрутки и затем перед прокруткой опять возвращать на место. Результат это не принесло, рулетка так же стояла на месте